# sed replace with backslash, double quote, single quote

Tags: sed

Can you give the sed command that will find `\"` and replace with `\\'` in a file.

For example line:

`LOG_FN=\"file_name\"`

will become

`LOG_FN=\\'file_name\\'`

By using this [template](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-text-in-files-in-linux-unix-shell/):

```
sed -i 's/old-text/new-text/g' input.txt
```

I tried following sed commands:

```
sed -i 's/\\\"/\\\\\'/g' input.txt

sed -i "s/\\\"/\\\\'/g" input.txt
```

Unfortunately they fail because what I am looking for is a string substitution for `\"` while commands I tried change individual `"` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't escape a single quote inside single quotes. Your second attempt needs more backslashes: Remember, inside double quotes, the shell processes one layer of backslashes, so you have to double each backslash which should make it through to `sed`.

```
sed "s/\\\\\"/\\\\\\\\'/g" input.txt
```

After the shell has processed the double-quoted string, the script which ends up being executed is

```
s/\\"/\\\\'/g
```

where the first pair of backslashes produce a literal backslash in the matching regex, and each pair of backslashes in the replacement produce one literal backslash in the output.

Demo: https://ideone.com/XqfwbV